# How to prove that $\vdash\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi$ is a theorem in S5?

Tags: modal-logic

I want to prove that $\vdash\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi$ is a theorem in S5

I have **S5** definition :

> \begin{align*}
> T&:\Box p\rightarrow p\\
> 5&:\Diamond p\rightarrow \Box\Diamond p\\
> K&:\Box (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(\Box p\rightarrow \Box \phi)\\
> Nec&:\frac{\phi}{\Box\phi}
> \end{align*}

And **theorem** definition :

> A formula is a **theorem** of S5 $\Leftrightarrow\phi$ is **valid** in all frames *where* R is an **equivalence relation**

\begin{align}
&\neg (\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi),w_i\mbox{ as an hypothesis}\\
&\phi,w_i \mbox{ from }R_\neg \mbox{ on } 1\\
&\Diamond\phi,w_i\mbox{ from }R_\neg \mbox{ on } 1\\
\end{align}

I'm not sure I have here an equivalence relation to conclude that

Therefore $\phi$ is valid in all frames and $\vdash\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi$ is a theorem in S5

#### Third attempt

\begin{align}
\neg\phi\rightarrow\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ contrapositive of }T\\
\neg\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi,w_i \mbox{ negation of }1
\end{align}

Therefore $\phi$ is valid and $\vdash\phi\rightarrow\neg\Box\neg\phi$ is a theorem in S5

Comment: The first line of your proof must be: $¬(ϕ→¬ \square ¬ϕ)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Indeed, my bad

Comment: Now it is quite easy: $w_i \Vdash \square \lnot \phi$ implies $w_j \Vdash \lnot \phi$ for every $w_j : w_iRw_j$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't my third attempt even easier ? constructing it from **S5** properties ? (I am still not sure about how to use the $w_i$ though)

Answer (score 2):

1) $\Box\neg\phi\to\neg\phi$, obtained by substituting $\neg\phi$ for $p$ in the $\mathbf{T}$ axiom.

2) $\neg\neg\phi\to\neg\Box\neg\phi$, by contraposition from (1).

3) $\phi\to\neg\neg\phi$, by classical logic (a tautology).

4) $\phi\to\neg\Box\neg\phi$, by syllogism from (3) and (2).

That's it.